# How to use, at one-time, an expression to replace encoding errors in QGIS 2.18.14?

Tags: qgis, expression, replace

I need to replace several encoding errors in just one task.

I have this:

[image]

If I change the encoding to UTF8, the "Label" field is correct, but the error passes to the other field, "name".

Instead of using this expressão several times, how to assemble the expression to do it all at once?

- replace( "name" , 'Ã³','ó')
- replace( "name" , 'Ã©', 'é')
- replace( "name" , 'Ã¢', 'â')
- replace( "name" , 'Ãº', 'ú')
- replace( "name" , 'Ã¡', 'á')
- replace( "name" , 'Ã£', 'ã')
- replace( "name" , 'Ã§', 'ç')
- replace( "name" , 'Ãµ', 'õ')
- replace( "name" , 'Ã?', 'Á')
- replace( "name" , 'Ã­Â­', 'í')
- replace( "name" , 'Ãª', 'ê')
- replace( "name" , 'Âº', 'º')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply nest the `replace` calls, using an expression like:

```
replace( replace( replace( "name" , 'Ã¢', 'â') , 'Ã©', 'é') , 'Ã³','ó')
```